# Two flex elements, why does one center vertically when shrunk?

Tags: html, css, video, flexbox

We have a video as a flex element and a playbar as a flex element.  Video is 75% and playbar takes up rest minus paddding.  When the playbar is long and we reduce screen size, the video shrinks too just fine but loses its top alignment and centers vertically on the playbar.  How do we keep video on the top using flex?

```css
.cat-main {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.cat-video {
  ms-flex-preferred-size: 75%;
  flex-basis: 75%;
  max-width: 75%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 43.5%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cat-playlist {
  padding-left: 5px;
  ms-flex-preferred-size: 23%;
  flex-basis: 23%;
  max-width: 23%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.cat-video iframe,
.cat-video object,
.cat-video embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cat-main">
  <div class="cat-video">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kCT0Z23rcsc" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="cat-playlist">
    really long playlist code<br>
 really long playlist code<br>
 really long playlist code<br>
 really long playlist code<br>
 really long playlist code<br>
 really long playlist code<br>
  really long playlist code<br>
 really long playlist code<br>
 really long playlist code<br>
 really long playlist code<br>
 really long playlist code<br>
 really long playlist code<br>
  really long playlist code<br>
 really long playlist code<br>
 really long playlist code<br>
 really long playlist code<br>
 really long playlist code<br>
 really long playlist code<br>
  really long playlist code<br>
 really long playlist code<br>
 really long playlist code<br>
 really long playlist code<br>
 really long playlist code<br>
 really long playlist code<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: padding-top:XX% on a flex child (to maintain a ratio) in firefox does not work :(

Comment: @GCyrillus - yes in FF it makes video same height as playlist - when video is actually bigger and should go full width.  However we have no FF users so not concerned but yes should clean up that just in case.  in most cases we start out with video taller than playlist and then once it goes to around 800-900px... boom video is smaller and centers vertically on the playlist.  I have tried aligning it to top using flex code... nothing works.

Comment: have you tried: align-self:flex-star; on .cat-video, or margin:0 0 auto; ? to  (do you need that flex-wrap too ?)

Comment: @GCyrillus - the align-self: flex-start helps once the container becomes very small - we don't support that small yet but doesn't hurt to add it.  The margin doesn't help.  We don't need the flex-wrap but it doesn't break this part.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Can you add some more details? https://jsfiddle.net/g9cgn8bo/1/

Comment: I just updated the embed version of the youtube link, is this close to what you experiment ? If it is about the content inside the frame, your style sheet cannot do anything about it since it is another document(uri) outside the current one :(

Comment: @GCyrillus -  Ugggg no.   I would be perfectly happy with that and that is what I thought I was building.   One of the containers it is in must be effecting it.  I will enter more html/css for the surrounding containers later today.

Comment: @GCyrillus - Actually it is the iframed container that is causing the issue.  Meaning that the "video" being embedded is taking on a height but the video itself isn't that tall - so it centers itself vertically.  Let me get some video code in there iframed that will mimic what I am experiencing.